# Custom DataAnnotations Validator Derived from RegularExpressionAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

[The Gu provides an example](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) of how you might create a custom validator that overrides RegularExpressionAttribute .

The advantage of this is that you don't have to [create a custom Model Validator](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx) but I can't get it to work.

Given the following code:

```
public class NameAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute {
    public NameAttribute()
        : base(@"^[\w\s\-\']+$") {
    }
}
```

This works:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\w\s\-\']+$")]
```

But this doesn't:

```
[Name]
```

Have I misunderstood an aspect of Scott's example or is the example flawed in that MVC doesn't support derived types out of the box, so actually I will have to create a a corresponding ModelValidator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cracked it! Add the following to Global.asax.cs Application_Start()

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(NameAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

Comment: Great! Was going mad as well!

Answer (score 1):

If u wanna a client validation, you should Register a server-side adapter for remote validation.

See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336030.aspx

and here:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/remote-validation-with-aspnet-mvc-2.html

Comment: I was given the impression, that I would get this out of the box, because I was inheriting from a built-in attribute. Is this not the case?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not so easy =(

I think that You should at least add the DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter() in the global.asax

Comment: +1 Ah, excellent. Just came to exactly the same conclusion. When I have more time, I think I'll have a look at expanding the Default Factory to include derived types.