# Best Data annotation for a Decimal(18,2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a column inside my sql server 2008 wih type of `Decimal(18,2)`. But on entity framework what is the best data annotation validation I can apply to this property, inside my asp.net MVC web application ?

Comment: Do you mean, to restrict it to 2 decimal places?

Comment: yes , so that no exception will be raised on the database !!

Comment: @jumpingcode's answered correctly below, you should accept.

Answer (score 77):

There is no explicit data annotation for a decimal so you need to use two separate ones to add constraints.

### Two Decimal Points

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$")]
```

This regular expression will make sure that the property has at most two decimal places.

### Max 18 digits

```
[Range(0, 9999999999999999.99)]
```

Assuming you aren't accepting any negative numbers. Otherwise, replace `0` with `-9999999999999999.99`.

### Result

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$")]
[Range(0, 9999999999999999.99)]
public decimal Property { get; set; }
```

Comment: this regular expression is invalid
Try input 1234m12 and it will pass the expression. Dot needs to be escaped as it's treated as any character.
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]

Comment: I believe the regular expression in your example should be "^\d*.\d{0,2}$".  Otherwise a single digit value would be unacceptable, yet a single digit value should be acceptable to OP.

Comment: @Jay How to have decimal like (0.1234) or (456.0009) ?

Comment: Great answer, however, I found the regex forced you to have to have decimal places which for my use case wasn't what I needed, so a regex to make the decimal places optional is: "^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"    This works great for entry of currency, etc.

Comment: Important to note that `RegularExpressionAttribute` takes current culture into account when converting the value being tested into a string (in order to test it against the supplied regular expression) so if the current culture's decimal point is a comma (which it may be) then you'll need to account for that in your regular expression.

Answer (score 27):

I think @jumpingcode's answer can be combined into one `RegularExpressionAttribute`.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(0|-?\d{0,16}(\.\d{0,2})?)$")]
public decimal Property
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

This can be used for any `precision` and `scale`. The 16 is replaced by `precision` - `scale` and the 2 is replaced by the `scale`. The regular expression should match numbers entered like `###`, `0.##`, `.##`, `0`, and `###.##` as well as negative values.

Comment: If this was going to be used regularly, extending the RegularExpression attribute would probably be the best option. Then you could just have an attribute where you provide the precision and scale.

Answer (score 24):

In **EF Core 6**

You can simply use:

```
[Precision(18,2)]
public decimal Property{ get; set; }
```

Comment: That doesn't validate the precision value though. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#precision-and-scale

Answer (score 15):

If you write the 'column' annotation, will work fine

```
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 6)")]
    public decimal Foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: It is not working on ASPNET MVC. I get this message when I run migration `The store type 'decimal(18, 8)' could not be found in the SqlServer provider manifest`

Comment: Same result for me too with this approach.

Answer (score 11):

For a different approach which some may consider more readable, you can override the OnModelCreating method of your DbContext to set precision, like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

           modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
                    .Property(x => x.TheProprty)
                    .HasPrecision(18, 2);
    }
```

Advantage: strongly typed vs custom regular expression

Disadvantage: can't see it on the class with just a scan

Answer (score 7):

Following on from @Schmalls example (and comment re building it into an attribute) I've created a working example (uses C# 6 string interpolation):

```
public class PrecisionAndScaleAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public PrecisionAndScaleAttribute(int precision, int scale) : base($@"^(0|-?\d{{0,{precision - scale}}}(\.\d{{0,{scale}}})?)$")
    {

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[PrecisionAndScale(6, 2, ErrorMessage = "Total Cost must not exceed $9999.99")]
public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
```

Comment: **Great idea for reusability**! *Important Note*: that [`RegularExpressionAttribute` subclasses will not automatically emit client side validation attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634265/1366033).  To do so, you need to call `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(PrecisionAndScaleAttribute),typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));`

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be the correct answer ( the above answers either restrict valid numbers that can be inserted into a data type of Decimal(18,2) or cause compile errors if you apply them to your code -- please confirm for yourself):

Use the following two constraints together:

**Two Decimal Points**

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.?\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Target Price; Maximum Two Decimal Points.")]
```

**Max 18 digits**

```
  [Range(0, 9999999999999999.99, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Target Price; Max 18 digits")]
```

Answer (score 2):

.net core/5/6 solution that works 2021

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ScalePrecisionValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private int _scale;
    private int _precision;

    public ScalePrecisionValidationAttribute(int scale, int precision)
    {
        _scale = scale;
        _precision = precision;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), $@"^(0|-?\d{{0,{_scale-_precision}}}(\.\d{{0,{_precision}}})?)$"))
            {
                return new ValidationResult($"Allowed scale: {_scale}, precision: {_precision}");
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

use as

```
[ScalePrecisionValidationAttribute(8, 3)]
public decimal Weight { get; set; }
```

you might want to add/modify additional guards depending on the use-case. p.s. I have used the `Regex` pattern from one of the other answers

Comment: IMHO call `SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale` and check if the result is equal. So you can avoid formatting strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [Range(1,(double) decimal.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="value should be between{1} and {2}."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using almost excplusively (b/c it's simple and works)

```
[Range(typeof(decimal), "0", "1")]
public decimal Split { get; set; }
```

Then if I need to convert back to double I add a conversion

```
(double)model.Split
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ahmad Kelany's answer.

From the Microsoft documentation [Entity Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt)

> Entity Framework does not do any validation of precision or scale before passing data to the provider. It is up to the provider or data store to validate as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

While using @Alex's code, I encountered an issue when the culture info was set to "es" (Spanish). The decimal was printed with the format of "12,34", and the attribute wasn't working properly. I was able to fix this and make some other changes so that it works as closely to other components (such as using braces for parameters when using the ErrorMessage property"

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PrecisionAndScaleAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _precision;
    private readonly int _scale;

    public PrecisionAndScaleAttribute(int precision, int scale)
        : base(() => "The field {0} only allows decimals with precision {1} and scale {2}.")
    {
        _precision = precision;
        _scale = scale;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        if (value is null)
            return true;

        if (value is not decimal decimalValue)
            return false;

        string? precisionValue = decimalValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return precisionValue is null || Regex.IsMatch(precisionValue, $@"^(0|-?\d{{0,{_precision - _scale}}}(\.\d{{0,{_scale}}})?)$");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override of <see cref="ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The user-visible name to include in the formatted message.</param>
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        => string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, _precision, _scale);
}
```