# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Custom Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to implement a custom validator for phone number on an ASP.NET MVC 3 App I am writing.  I have wriiten the code for the custom validator as below

```
public class PhoneNumberValidator : ValidationAttribute 
{


    public PhoneNumberValidator() : base("The Phone Number is not Valid")
    {
    }
    public override bool  IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string phonenumber = value.ToString();

            var regex = new Regex(@"^(?:[0-9]+(?:-[0-9])?)*$");

            if (regex.IsMatch(phonenumber))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in my Model class I have the following :

```
    [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Is Phone Number Required")]
    [PhoneNumberValidator]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

However when I run my app and click the proceed button on the page it does not throw an error if the value entered is letters although if I set a breakpoint I can see that the value is being read in to string phonenumber ok.  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689444/custom-dataannotations-validator-derived-from-regularexpressionattribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be reinventing a wheel. Why not use the existing regex validator:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Is Phone Number Required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]+(?:-[0-9])?)*$")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This being said validation is triggered by the model binder, so make sure that the controller action you are submitting the form to takes the view model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model is invalid => redisplay view
        return View(model);
    }

    // at this stage the model is valid => you could do some processing here 
    // and redirect
    ...
}
```

or use the `TryUpdateModel` method (personally I prefer the previous approach though):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(FormCollection some_Dummy_Parameter_Thats_Not_Used_At_All_But_Which_We_Need_To_Avoid_The_Method_Overloading_Error_With_The_GET_Action_Which_Has_The_Same_Name)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    if (!TryUpdateModel(model))
    {
        // the model is invalid => redisplay view
        return View(model);
    }

    // at this stage the model is valid => you could do some processing here 
    // and redirect
    ...
}
```

Also in order to display the error message somewhere make sure that you have a corresponding placeholder in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
```

or use a validation summary helper:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Comment: I know I could use the regex as you have mentioned - it will be used in multiple locations on numerous pages however so for a better design I want a validations folder that will contain all the custom validation classes, so ones for phone number, post/zip codes/dates, etc - thanks for you response though - I will look into it.

Comment: Correct. In this case having a custom validator seems appropriate.

Comment: Many Thanks - I think it was the placeholders on the page I was missing